# Passing data to Open CTI softphone from Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I want to pass some data captured in `Salesforce` to my `Open CTI` softphone and may have to invoke some event from `Salesforce` like hangup, transfer etc. Any idea how to achieve that? I can use `jQuery` to do so. Is there any better way to do so or any inbuilt feature?

Comment: first of all how can you login to softphone each user in openCTI call center because if you can explain then i say what actual problem you are facing and what is the solution for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used HTML5 postMessage to pass message from Salesforce to softPhone in JSON string.